# Spinnaker unable to communicate with kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, spinnaker

I am trying to deploy spinnaker locally with minikube and minio, i have everything setted up, my kubernetes cluster is up and running with a composed app on it, details below:

---

```
|          NAME             | READY | UP-TO-DATE | AVAILABLE | AGE |
|---------------------------|-------|------------|-----------|-----|
| deployment.extensions/api |  1/1  |      1     |     1     | 18s |
| deployment.extensions/db  |  1/1  |      1     |     1     | 18s |
```

I configured both, my kubernetes and storage on my hal config, i will paste it below as well, when i try to deploy using "sudo hal deploy apply" i get the following error:

> - WARNING You have not specified a Kubernetes context in your   halconfig, Spinnaker will use "minikube" instead. ? We recommend
>     explicitly setting a context in your halconfig, to   ensure changes to
>     your kubeconfig won't break your deployment.
>
> **! ERROR** Unable to communicate with your Kubernetes cluster: An   error
>   has occurred.. ? Unable to authenticate with your Kubernetes cluster.
>   Try using   kubectl to verify your credentials.
>
> Problems in default.security:
>
> - WARNING Your UI or API domain does not have override base URLs   set even though your Spinnaker deployment is a Distributed deployment on a
>     remote cloud provider. As a result, you will need to open SSH tunnels
>     against   that deployment to access Spinnaker. ? We recommend that you
>     instead configure an authentication   mechanism (OAuth2, SAML2, or
>     x509) to make it easier to access Spinnaker   securely, and then
>     register the intended Domain and IP addresses that your   publicly
>     facing services will be using.
> - Failed to prep Spinnaker deployment

Here is my hal config:

```
currentDeployment: default
deploymentConfigurations:
- name: default
  version: ''
  providers:
    appengine:
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
    aws:
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
      bakeryDefaults:
        baseImages: []
      defaultKeyPairTemplate: '{{name}}-keypair'
      defaultRegions:
      - name: us-west-2
      defaults:
        iamRole: BaseIAMRole
    ecs:
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
    azure:
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
      bakeryDefaults:
        templateFile: azure-linux.json
        baseImages: []
    dcos:
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
      clusters: []
    dockerRegistry:
      enabled: true
      accounts:
      - name: my-docker-registry
        requiredGroupMembership: []
        providerVersion: V1
        permissions: {}
        address: https://index.docker.io
        username: <sensitive> (this is my actual username)
        password: <sensitive> (this is my actual password)
        email: fake.email@spinnaker.io
        cacheIntervalSeconds: 30
        clientTimeoutMillis: 60000
        cacheThreads: 1
        paginateSize: 100
        sortTagsByDate: false
        trackDigests: false
        insecureRegistry: false
        repositories:
        - ericstoppel1/atixlabs
      primaryAccount: my-docker-registry
    google:
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
      bakeryDefaults:
        templateFile: gce.json
        baseImages: []
        zone: us-central1-f
        network: default
        useInternalIp: false
    kubernetes:
      enabled: true
      accounts:
      - name: my-k8s-account
        requiredGroupMembership: []
        providerVersion: V1
        permissions: {}
        dockerRegistries:
        - accountName: my-docker-registry
          namespaces: []
        configureImagePullSecrets: true
        cacheThreads: 1
        namespaces: []
        omitNamespaces: []
        kinds: []
        omitKinds: []
        customResources: []
        cachingPolicies: []
        kubeconfigFile: /home/osboxes/.kube/config
        oAuthScopes: []
        onlySpinnakerManaged: false
      primaryAccount: my-k8s-account
    oracle:
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
      bakeryDefaults:
        templateFile: oci.json
        baseImages: []
    cloudfoundry:
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
  deploymentEnvironment:
    size: SMALL
    type: Distributed
    accountName: my-k8s-account
    updateVersions: true
    consul:
      enabled: false
    vault:
      enabled: false
    customSizing: {}
    sidecars: {}
    initContainers: {}
    hostAliases: {}
    affinity: {}
    nodeSelectors: {}
    gitConfig:
      upstreamUser: spinnaker
    livenessProbeConfig:
      enabled: false
    haServices:
      clouddriver:
        enabled: false
        disableClouddriverRoDeck: false
      echo:
        enabled: false
  persistentStorage:
    persistentStoreType: s3
    azs: {}
    gcs:
      rootFolder: front50
    redis: {}
    s3:
      bucket: spin-763f86d5-10ba-497e-9348-264fc353edec
      rootFolder: front50
      pathStyleAccess: false
      endpoint: https://localhost:9001
      accessKeyId: AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
      secretAccessKey: wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
    oracle: {}
  features:
    auth: false
    fiat: false
    chaos: false
    entityTags: false
    jobs: false
  metricStores:
    datadog:
      enabled: false
      tags: []
    prometheus:
      enabled: false
      add_source_metalabels: true
    stackdriver:
      enabled: false
    period: 30
    enabled: false
  notifications:
    slack:
      enabled: false
    twilio:
      enabled: false
      baseUrl: https://api.twilio.com/
  timezone: America/Los_Angeles
  ci:
    jenkins:
      enabled: false
      masters: []
    travis:
      enabled: false
      masters: []
    wercker:
      enabled: false
      masters: []
    concourse:
      enabled: false
      masters: []
    gcb:
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
  repository:
    artifactory:
      enabled: false
      searches: []
  security:
    apiSecurity:
      ssl:
        enabled: false
    uiSecurity:
      ssl:
        enabled: false
    authn:
      oauth2:
        enabled: false
        client: {}
        resource: {}
        userInfoMapping: {}
      saml:
        enabled: false
        userAttributeMapping: {}
      ldap:
        enabled: false
      x509:
        enabled: false
      iap:
        enabled: false
      enabled: false
    authz:
      groupMembership:
        service: EXTERNAL
        google:
          roleProviderType: GOOGLE
        github:
          roleProviderType: GITHUB
        file:
          roleProviderType: FILE
        ldap:
          roleProviderType: LDAP
      enabled: false
  artifacts:
    bitbucket:
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
    gcs:
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
    oracle:
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
    github:
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
    gitlab:
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
    http:
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
    helm:
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
    s3:
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
    maven:
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
    templates: []
  pubsub:
    enabled: false
    google:
      enabled: false
      pubsubType: GOOGLE
      subscriptions: []
      publishers: []
  canary:
    enabled: false
    serviceIntegrations:
    - name: google
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
      gcsEnabled: false
      stackdriverEnabled: false
    - name: prometheus
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
    - name: datadog
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
    - name: signalfx
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
    - name: aws
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
      s3Enabled: false
    reduxLoggerEnabled: true
    defaultJudge: NetflixACAJudge-v1.0
    stagesEnabled: true
    templatesEnabled: true
    showAllConfigsEnabled: true
  webhook:
    trust:
      enabled: false
```

I have my kubernetes config and can acces to it, so, separately it all seems to work, what may be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As per issue reported:

> WARNING You have not specified a Kubernetes context in your halconfig,
>   Spinnaker will use "minikube" instead.

I don't see any Kuberenetes [context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/) entry defined in your `hal` config, find [here](https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/tutorials/codelabs/kubernetes-v2-source-to-prod/#add-your-kubernetes-accounts) dedicated chapter from Spinnaker guideline document.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the kubernetes details to the halyard context.

```
hal config provider kubernetes account add <ACCOUNT>
hal config provider kubernetes enable
```

This link can be used for reference: https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/halyard/commands/